# How to filter multiple nested serializer in django rest framwork

Tags: django, generics, serialization, filter, django-rest-framework

I've `Tripserializer` class contain nested serializer `PackageSerializer`, inside it there is nested serializer `PriceSerializer` .

```
class Trip_apiView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset= Trip.objects.all()
    serializer_class=TripSerializer

class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    price=PriceSerializer(source='trip_price', many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Package
        exclude = ('is_active', 'create_date', 'modify_date')

class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Price
        exclude = ('is_active', 'create_date', 'modify_date')
```

this my `views`:

```
class Trip_apiView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset= Trip.objects.all().order_by('title')
    serializer_class=TripSerializer
```

I receive list of all trips from `GET` method like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 137,
    "title": "dqw",
    "package": 
         {
             "id": 139,
             "price": 
             {
                  "id": 78,
                  "price": 2.2,
                  "sale_price": 2.2,
                  "trip_package": 139
              },
              "package_name": "wfe",
              "description": "fwe",
              "trip": 137
         },
  },
  {....},
  {....}
]
```

How Can I Filter this List of trips by `price` and by `title`

Models.py :
[image: models.py]

Comment: Can you post your models?

Comment: Post updated .. take look on models now

Comment: Where do you get `price` and `title`? You can use a filtered prefetch in this case

Comment: @BrianDestura title is field of Trip Class and price is field of Price class.. I get this json data from Trip_apiView, so can you explain little more your answer by code ?

Comment: I think you should refrain from using float to represent currency values. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3730040/14999453